# How to get Menu or MenuItem width in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx-8, menuitem

I am extending the default `Menu` and `MenuItem` class to add some animated effects to it.

The problem is that I need to know the width and height of the `Menu` and `MenuItem` I'm working on. This classes doesn't extend `Node` or `Region` so there are no public methods to get their size. The size is composed by the text size inside the `MenuItem` plus the corresponding default padding, I can calculate how much space the text takes, but I can't get how much padding the `MenuItem` has neither.

There is a method called `impl_styleableGetNode()` that returns a `Node` but it always returns null for me.

Is there anyway to get the size? `MenuBar` also doesn't seems to expose any helpful method for this.

**EDIT:**

Here is my class, I'm trying to implement [this](http://plumblog.herokuapp.com/2014/12/10/JavaFX-button-with-ripple-effect/) material design button into the `Menu` class. Basically I render all the button using the `setGraphic()` method. It's working perfectly but I'm using the `Pane` width which doesn't take into account the padding of the `Menu` so the effect is not complete.

```
public class MaterialDesignMenu extends Menu {

    private Pane stackPane = new Pane();
    private Label label = new Label();

    private Circle circleRipple;
    private Rectangle rippleClip = new Rectangle();
    private Duration rippleDuration =  Duration.millis(250);
    private double lastRippleHeight = 0;
    private double lastRippleWidth = 0;
    private Color rippleColor = new Color(1, 0, 0, 0.3);

    public MaterialDesignMenu() {
        init("");
    }

    public MaterialDesignMenu(String text) {
        init(text);
    }

    public MaterialDesignMenu(String text, Node graphic) {
        init(text);
    }

    private void init(String text){
        label.setText(text);
        createRippleEffect();

        stackPane.getChildren().addAll(circleRipple, label);
        setGraphic(stackPane);
    }

    private void createRippleEffect() {
        circleRipple = new Circle(0.1, rippleColor);
        circleRipple.setOpacity(0.0);
        // Optional box blur on ripple - smoother ripple effect
        //circleRipple.setEffect(new BoxBlur(3, 3, 2));
        // Fade effect bit longer to show edges on the end of animation
        final FadeTransition fadeTransition = new FadeTransition(rippleDuration, circleRipple);
        fadeTransition.setInterpolator(Interpolator.EASE_OUT);
        fadeTransition.setFromValue(1.0);
        fadeTransition.setToValue(0.0);
        final Timeline scaleRippleTimeline = new Timeline();
        final SequentialTransition parallelTransition = new SequentialTransition();
        parallelTransition.getChildren().addAll(
                scaleRippleTimeline,
                fadeTransition
        );
        // When ripple transition is finished then reset circleRipple to starting point
        parallelTransition.setOnFinished(event -> {
            circleRipple.setOpacity(0.0);
            circleRipple.setRadius(0.1);
        });

        stackPane.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, event -> {
            parallelTransition.stop();
            // Manually fire finish event
            parallelTransition.getOnFinished().handle(null);
            circleRipple.setCenterX(event.getX());
            circleRipple.setCenterY(event.getY());

            // Recalculate ripple size if size of button from last time was changed
            if (stackPane.getWidth() != lastRippleWidth || stackPane.getHeight() != lastRippleHeight) {
                lastRippleWidth = stackPane.getWidth();
                lastRippleHeight = stackPane.getHeight();
                rippleClip.setWidth(lastRippleWidth);
                rippleClip.setHeight(lastRippleHeight);
                /*
                // try block because of possible null of Background, fills ...
                try {
                    rippleClip.setArcHeight(stackPane.getBackground().getFills().get(0).getRadii().getTopLeftHorizontalRadius());
                    rippleClip.setArcWidth(stackPane.getBackground().getFills().get(0).getRadii().getTopLeftHorizontalRadius());
                    circleRipple.setClip(rippleClip);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }*/

                circleRipple.setClip(rippleClip);
                // Getting 45% of longest button's length, because we want edge of ripple effect always visible
                double circleRippleRadius = Math.max(stackPane.getHeight(), stackPane.getWidth()) * 0.45;
                final KeyValue keyValue = new KeyValue(circleRipple.radiusProperty(), circleRippleRadius, Interpolator.EASE_OUT);
                final KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(rippleDuration, keyValue);
                scaleRippleTimeline.getKeyFrames().clear();
                scaleRippleTimeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
            }
            parallelTransition.playFromStart();
        });
    }

    public void setRippleColor(Color color) {
        circleRipple.setFill(color);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code? This might be tricky to do; you may be able to make it work with `MenuItem.getGraphic().getWidth()` but it depends on how you have things set up.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to listen to `parentPopupProperty` changes of `MenuItem`. When you get the instance of parent popup than register listener for `skinProperty` of `ContextMenu` (parentPopup). When you get the skin then you can get `MenuItemContainer` which is `Node` equivalent of `MenuItem` and you can listen to `widthProperty` or `heightProperty` changes of `MenuItemContainer`.

Note: `skinProperty` change is fired just before `ContextMenu` is shown on the screen.

Custom class extending `MenuItem` class:

```
public class CstMenuItem extends MenuItem {

    public CstMenuItem() {
        // Create custom menu item listener.
        new CstMenuItemListener(this);
    }

    /*
     * Returns MenuItemContainer node associated with this menu item
     * which can contain:
     *   1. label node of type Label for displaying menu item text,
     *   2. right node of type Label for displaying accelerator text,
     *      or an arrow if it's a Menu,
     *   3. graphic node for displaying menu item icon, and
     *   4. left node for displaying either radio button or check box.
     * 
     * This is basically rewritten impl_styleableGetNode() which
     * should not be used since it's marked as deprecated.
     */
    public ContextMenuContent.MenuItemContainer getAssociatedNode() {
        ContextMenu contextMenu = getParentPopup();
        ContextMenuSkin skin = (ContextMenuSkin) contextMenu.getSkin();
        ContextMenuContent content = (ContextMenuContent) skin.getNode();
        // Items container contains MenuItemContainer nodes and Separator nodes.
        Parent itemsContainer = content.getItemsContainer();
        List<Node> children = itemsContainer.getChildrenUnmodifiable();
        for (Node child : children) {
            if (child instanceof ContextMenuContent.MenuItemContainer) {
                ContextMenuContent.MenuItemContainer menuItemContainer =
                        (ContextMenuContent.MenuItemContainer) child;
                if (menuItemContainer.getItem() == this) {
                    return menuItemContainer;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Custom `MenuItem` listener class:

```
public class CstMenuItemListener implements ChangeListener {

    private CstMenuItem menuItem;
    private ContextMenu parentPopup;
    private Region menuItemContainer;

    public CstMenuItemListener(CstMenuItem menuItem) {
        this.menuItem = menuItem;
        menuItem.parentPopupProperty().addListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
        if (observable == menuItem.parentPopupProperty()) {
            parentPopup = (ContextMenu) newValue;
            parentPopup.skinProperty().addListener(this);
        } else if (observable == parentPopup.skinProperty()) {
            menuItemContainer = menuItem.getAssociatedNode();
            menuItemContainer.widthProperty().addListener(this);
            menuItemContainer.heightProperty().addListener(this);
        } else if (observable == menuItemContainer.widthProperty()) {
            System.out.println("width: " + (double) newValue);
        } else if (observable == menuItemContainer.heightProperty()) {
            System.out.println("height: " + (double) newValue);
        }
    }
}
```